# Not able to override default timeout while using explicit wait mechanism in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, ui-automation, visibility, cypress-wait-until

I am using cypress-wait-until plugin to apply explicit wait in our framework. When I use it and maximum time given is say 30000 milliseconds, so ideally it should wait maximum 300000 ms (30 seconds) for element to be visible but it timesout after 4 seconds which is a default timeout for cypress commands.

```
    cy.waitUntil(() => cy.get('div.tabs div:nth-child(3)').should('be.visible') ,{timeout:30000})
```

I would like to know what changes I should and in which file so that I can override default timeout prescribed for cypress. It would be great if community provides some solution in this regard.

Comment: No, `cy.waitUntil` is not at all needed for this test. If your timeout is not sufficient, increase it. How can that no be obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `cy.waitUntil()`, change `cy.get()` to jQuery. That way the only timeout active is the one provided to `cy.waitUntil()`.

```js
cy.waitUntil(() => {
  return Cypress.$('div.tabs div:nth-child(3):visible').length
}, {timeout:30000})
```

Comment: thanks Aladin, your solution worked. Thank you for your efforts and contribution.

Answer (score 6):

Using the wait-until package isn't actually necessary, Cypress has built-in timeouts on each command. The package is also somewhat flaky in my experience.

You can just achieve what you describe just using this

```js
cy.get('div.tabs div:nth-child(3)', {timeout:30_000}).should('be.visible')
```

To change the default, do as daun suggests if using Cypress v9 or less, or in the file `cypress.config.js` for versions above.

Or add the timeout as a parameter to the test

```js
it('tests my framework', {timeout:30_000}, () => {
```

You can read more in the Cypress documentation.

Comment: these options provide fix period of timeout and in case cypress able to access element early then cypress has to wait unnecessarily for rest of time provided in the request.

Comment: Nope, you have confused `timeout` with `wait`. It's fundamental to testing web pages, I suggest you get up to speed on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried increasing the [global timeout](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Timeouts) to a value larger than your wait timeout in your `cypress.json`?

```json
{
  "defaultCommandTimeout": 35000
}
```

Comment: this will result in increasing wait time for all the actions. We want to dynamically put timeout so that once cypress gets element then wait stops and action happens.